# Nancy.LightningCache - Throws exception when AsCachable() is called

Tags: nancy

I am trying to use the Nancy addin `Nancy.LightningCache`

According to the [docs](https://github.com/creamdog/Nancy.LightningCache) I should be able to set up my caching easily, like this:

**Bootstrapper**

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    this.EnableLightningCache(
            container.Resolve<IRouteResolver>(), 
            ApplicationPipelines, 
            new[] {"id", "claim", "query", "take", "skip"});
}
```

**Route**

```
Get["/profile"] = _ => 
View["UserProfileView", Model].AsCacheable(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));
```

When this route is called I get the following exception.

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
'Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.Negotiator' does not contain a definition for 'AsCacheable'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it.

**Working Route**

```
return View["HomeView", (object)Model].AsCacheable(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
```

You can see that I have been forced to explicitly cast my Model to an `object` in order to satisfy the signature of the `AsCachable` extension method.

The problem only shows up at runtime because my Model is an `ExpandoObject` and so a `dynamic` type.

Answer (score 2):

I just hacked this https://gist.github.com/4191120 together and it worked. All using 0.13 nugets